# why it's impossible to dereference a particular array index with the pointer notation

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I have two different code examples. In the first code it is possible to dereference:

```
void getValue(int *myPointer)
{
    *myPointer = 10000;             
    return;
}


int main()
{
    int get_the_value = 2;
    getValue(&get_the_value);


    printf("The value of get_the_value = %d\n", get_the_value);
    return 0;


}
```

But in the code below it is not possible to dereference *B in func().
I have this code below from the internet and they said this:

"*B is a pointer to int, thus B[0] is an int, and you can't dereference an int.* "

But is *myPointer in the first code not an int type too?

**So my question is: Why does dereferencing work in the first code but not in the second code?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int *B){
    *B[0] = 5;
}

int main(void){

    int B[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[0]);
    func(&B);
    printf("b[0] = %d\n\n", B[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the result of `B[0]` is not `int*`, but `int`.

Comment: Because `*x` is not the same as `*x[0]`.

Comment: It's because in first case myPointer is a pointer to an int i.e. stores an address of an integer value but in the second case the variable B[0] is of type int i.e. stores an integer value.

Comment: `*B[0] = 5` is a sort of double dereference. Use `B[0] = 5`.

Comment: DeiDei what does result of B[0] mean?

Comment: @WeatherVane , why is this double reference. because it is an array?

Comment: The array you passed decays to a pointer. You should then index the pointer, as if it was an array.

Comment: i think i understand, it is because func(int *B){...} is the same like func(int B[]){...} ?

Comment: Exactly so, but remember that even if the (1D) array specifies its size, such as `func(int B[42])` that information will be ignored by the compiler an runtime. Except when you have a multi-dimensional array, where you have to define every dimension except the topmost, so the compiler knows how to generate code correctly. For example, a 2D array would need to be say `func(int B[][42])` and in this case the `42` is essential.

Answer (score 6):

`B[0]` is the same as `*(B + 0)`, which is the same as `*B`, all of which have type `int`.  So given the type of `B`, you can write *either* `B[0]` *or* `*B`.

**Edit**

You have a type mismatch which isn't helping things.

You've declared the *parameter* `B` in `func` to have type `int *`; like I said above, the expression `B[0]` is equivalent to `*(B + 0)`, which is equivalent to `*B`.  IOW, the subscript operator *implicitly* dereferences `B`.

In `main`, you've declared `B` as a 3-element array of `int`, so the type of the *expression* `B` is `int [3]`.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type `T [N]` will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type `T *`, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

However, when you call `func`, you pass the expression `&B`, which has type `int (*)[3]` (pointer to 3-element array of `int`).  `int *` and `int (*)[3]` aren't compatible types.  Now, it just so happens that both the expressions `B` and `&B` will evaluate to the same location (address of the first element of `B`), so the code will still "work" if you write either `*B` or `B[0]`.  However, you should change the call to `func` to be

```
func( B ); // no & operator.
```

Then the types will match up.

Comment: ok thanks, last question. *B is int. so what datatype is  *myPointer ?

Comment: @Sedem: if `myPointer` is declared as `int *myPointer;`, then the *expression* `*myPointer` has type `int`.